# How to put irregular shaped png image as background in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, background, background-image

Can I use an image for background as it retains its alpha?For example I want the   [linked page](http://codepen.io/ctjithinkrishna/pen/qEXOEv?editors=110)

`

```
<body>
     <div class="wrapper">
         <main>
             <section class="module parallax">
                 <div class="container">
                     <h1>LOREM</h1>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="module content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="containef">
           <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean    commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
            <p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div><!-- /#wrapper -->
</body>
```

`
with using an irregular image instead of blue background color.(I do not want to use rotation)

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 600px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("http://www.imgion.com/images/01/All-Flower-For-You-.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  section.module h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
  section.module p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 96px;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 160px;
  }
}
.content{
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px rgba(56,0,0,.8);

}
.containef{
  height:1500px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
.module:last-of-type{
 background-color: blue;
 transform:scalex(2) rotate(5deg) translatey(-50px);
 box-shadow: 0 0 100px rgba(56,0,0,.8);

}
.containef{
  transform: rotate(-5deg) scalex(.5) translatey(50px);
  text-style:justify;
}
div{
  background: transparent;
}
.wrapper{
  background: transparent;
}
```

If yes Can I use a similar svg file?
What I mean is I would like to use a similarly shaped image like [this.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-EZ-0sz3lSsR1RDS01qQjRXem8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you can use pretty much anything as a background image. have you even tried it?

Comment: I doubt you did not read my question!